# Converting data set (x,y) into a function f(x,y) .

Tags: numerical-methods

Is there any way by which I can find an equation satisfying  my data set , I know there are a number of curve fitting methods in numerical methods; but I want a new function ( equation ) for my data set . e.g. any function like log(a(tan(bx))) .

I know it's very vague to ask such a thing but I have a data from my experiment for which I want to establish my own equation .

If there are any definite steps by which researchers develop any equation out of the box from their experimental data ?

Thanks

Comment: There are infinitely many continuous functions passing through a finite set of points. It is better if you first decide your function like linear, quadratic, inverse, exponential etc. then to find your best fitting curve. Usually experimental data fit on "easier" functions rather than something like $\log ( 7 \tan (5x))$

Comment: No but how scientists and researcher come up with such novel equations, for simple example : The Newton's 1st law v = u + at , the stress-strain curve stress = K x (Strain) ^n . All these have must come from a definite experimental data set . Isn't it ?